# Useing sed to replace strings in a file from key-values in a TSV file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a TSV file with two columns (changes.txt). I want to replace every occurance from the first column in a file, with the value of the second column.

I have tried this:

`while IFS=$'\t' read -r changes.txt $var1 $var2 ; do sed -i -e "s/$var1/$var2/g" file.to.change.txt ; done`

Example changes.txt

```
cat   dog
cow   sheep
```

Example file to change.txt

```
cat
pelican
cow
goose
duck
pig
```

Expected output:

```
dog
pelican
sheep
goose
duck
pig
```

This gives errors. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do post samples of input and expected output in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following. Where firstFile is your file where you have line `cat   dog` and secondFile is other file.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in arr){$1=arr[$1]} 1' firstFile secondFile
```

In case you have tab separated then change `awk` to `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` in above code.

Comment: For the OP - note that this does full-string matching on both fields in both input files (unlike the attempt in your question which does partial regexp matching) and so it will work robustly no matter what characters/strings your input contains, including strings that are substrings of others (e.g. `cat` and `catfish`) and/or contain regexp metachars like `.` or `*`, and/or backrefence chars like `&`, and it will work portably using any awk in any shell on every Unix box.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(.*)\t(.*)/s#\\<\1\\>#\2#/' tsvFile | sed -i -f - fileToChange
```

Manufacture a sed script and apply it to the file to be amended.